# Creating a new user after install with encrypted home

Tags: 12.04

Just trying to set up a secondary user after install on 12.04. My last system was 10.04 and it allowed me to create a new user with an encrypted home partition but when creating a new user on 12.04 there is no option to encrypt home partition. Do I need to install another package or am I missing something?

Answer (score 19):

It is a bug of 12.04, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/816669).

You can workaround creating the user from terminal. The command is:
`adduser --encrypt-home username`  (change "username" for the user name you want).

Comment: The --encrypt-home switch is also missing. $ sudo useradd --encrypt-home newuser
useradd: unrecognised option '--encrypt-home' $ uname -a
Linux username -VGN-FZ11S 3.2.0-24-generic-pae ... i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Richard Did you run [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/useradd.8.html) or [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/adduser.8.html)? Both commands exist, but `adduser` is the one you want. (Also you'll need to run it as `root` with `sudo`, i.e., `sudo adduser --encrypt-home username`.)

Comment: for 15.10 I had to install package ecryptfs-utils before I could use --encrypt-home

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be fixed at the command line level.

```
sudo adduser --encrypt-home username
```

(Change "username" for the user name you want.)

Just worked for me in an up to date 12.04 Precise Pangolin ie.it created a new user with an encrypted home directory.

---

If you receive an error message :

```
adduser: unable to find a program named « ecryptfs-setup-private » in $PATH"...
```

Adding the package « ecryptfs-utils » solves this problem (thanks, apt-file...) :

```
apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

Comment: if accessing the user using `su`, make sure to run `ecryptfs-mount-private`

Answer (score 2):

You just need another user & group admin tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Then go to dash and search for *Users and Groups*. Add a new user and check *"Encrypt home folder to protect sensitive data"*.
Remember to take extra precautions if you don't want sensitive data to leak into the log files (eg. /var/log/), temp files (eg. /tmp), the swap space, etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work under 14.04.

Comment: Did not work in 18.04.